# how tensorflow handles complex gradient?

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

Let **z** is a complex variable, **C(z)** is its conjugation.
In complex analysis theory, the derivative of **C(z)** w.r.t **z** don't exist. But in tesnsorflow, we can calculate **dC(z)/dz** and the result is just **1**.
Here is an example:

```
x = tf.placeholder('complex64',(2,2))
y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.conj(x))
z = tf.gradients(y,x)
sess = tf.Session()
X = np.random.rand(2,2)+1.j*np.random.rand(2,2)
X = X.astype('complex64')
Z = sess.run(z,{x:X})[0]
```

The input **X** is

```
[[0.17014372+0.71475762j  0.57455420+0.00144318j]
 [0.57871044+0.61303568j  0.48074263+0.7623235j ]]
```

and the result **Z** is

```
[[1.-0.j  1.-0.j]
 [1.-0.j  1.-0.j]]
```

I don't understand why the gradient is set to be **1**?
And I want to know **how tensorflow handles the complex gradients in general**.

Comment: My guess is this is not supported. Does your work require this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

### **How?**

The equation used by Tensorflow for the gradient is:

[image: tf-grad-def]

Where the '*' means conjugate.

When using the definition of the partial derivatives wrt z and z* it uses Wirtinger Calculus. Wirtinger calculus enables to calculate the derivative wrt a complex variable for non-holomorphic functions. The Wirtinger definition is:

[image: wirtinger]

### **Why this definition?**

When using for example Complex-Valued Neural Networks (CVNN) the gradients will be used over non-holomorphic, real-valued scalar function of one or several complex variables, tensorflow definition of a gradient can then be written as:

[image]

This definition corresponds with the literature of CVNN like for example chapter 4 section 4.3 of [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=B2_bucoS5VAC&oi=fnd&pg=PT9&dq=Complex-Valued+Neural+Networks:+Advances+and+Applications&ots=eDbcbA-Zq5&sig=AAcoG9_26T9IsnpGNOKoelEdWAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Complex-Valued%20Neural%20Networks%3A%20Advances%20and%20Applications&f=false) or [Amin et al.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-24955-6_66) (between countless examples).

Answer (score 2):

Bit late, but I came across this issue recently too.

The key point is that TensorFlow *defines* the "gradient" of a complex-valued function f(z) of a complex variable as "the gradient of the real map F: (x,y) -> Re(f(x+iy)), expressed as a complex number" (the gradient of that real map is a vector in R^2, so we can express it as a complex number in the obvious way).

Presumably the reason for that definition is that in TF one is usually concerned with gradients for the purpose of running gradient descent on a loss function, and in particular for identifying the direction of maximum increase/decrease of that loss function. Using the above definition of gradient means that a complex-valued function of complex variables can be used as a loss function in a standard gradient descent algorithm, and the result will be that the real part of the function gets minimised (which seems to me a somewhat reasonable interpretation of "optimise this complex-valued function").

Now, to your question, an equivalent way to write that definition of gradient is

gradient(f) := dF/dx + idF/dy = conj(df/dz + dconj(f)/dz)

(you can easily verify that using the definition of d/dz). That's how TensorFlow handles complex gradients. As for the case of f(z):=conj(z), we have df/dz=0 (as you mention) and dconj(f)/dz=1, giving gradient(f)=1.

I wrote up a longer explanation here, if you're interested: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3348#issuecomment-512101921